# why does the funcions glewInit() should in write in the initializeGL()

Tags: qt, opengl, glew

I write the code below

```
glewInit();
glGenBuffers(2,buffers);
```

this code is called before initializeGL().it will cause an access conflict error.But when I put the
function glewInit() in initializeGl(). glGenBuffers() work fine.

Comment: Where is your `initializeGL()` function being called?

Comment: it is a function inherited from QGLWidget.To show the scene.I just inherit QGLWidget and rewrite the three funtions initializedGL,paintGL and resizeGL.

Comment: "it will cause an access conflict error", can you elaborate on that?  `glewInit()` just requires a valid context, which is why it works in `initializeGL()`.

Answer (score 0):

`glewInit()` requires a valid OpenGL context being bound and ready to function.

`glGenBuffers` (among other functions) is initialized by `glewInit()`. If GLEW cannot initialize successfully, for example because there's no valid OpenGL context around, then `glGenBuffers` contains a NULL pointer any trying to use it crashes the program.

In Qt a OpenGL context is warrented to be available only when `initializeGL` is called (and actually also only the other member methods ending with `…GL`, outside of those the context may not be bound).